# Execute code for each new thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it possible to tell the JVM (or some appropriate object) to execute a given block of code every time a new thread is created?

Comment: That's normal behaviour when creating a thread.  Sorry, but can't resist.. <g>

Comment: You could modify the Thread class, but only if there is no other option.

Comment: ...and how would I do that? (Wouldn't it be better to put your answer in an Answer instead of a Comment?)

Comment: What is your use case, why do you want to do that. Adding the reason why you want to achieve it can help to answer your question more precisely.

Comment: We have some issues with the context classloader not being correctly setup, resulting in a line of boilerplate that has to be copied and pasted at various spots in our codebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your use case, but you could also do Java byte [code instrumentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_%28computer_programming%29). This is, however, normally used for measuring, error tracing, profiling, etc. since it has noticeable performance impacts.

This can be done with [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/index.html), they have a [tutorial](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html) to get started or take a look at the guide [Add Logging at Class Load Time with Java Instrumentation](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/24/add-logging-at-class-load-time-with-instrumentation.html), they explain how to modify the Java code in a way, that code is added each time a method is entered and exited.

In your case you would do this only for special methods, either the `Thread()` constructor or the invocation of `Thread.start()`.

Answer (score 6):

No, not using standard Java.

Have a look at aspect oriented programming, such as [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/). You should probably be able to create a point-cut for the Thread constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Not every time a new thread is created. However, if you use a ThreadPoolExecutor to create new threads, you can specify a ThreadFactory, which can run a specific block of code every time a thread is created **by that factory**. A simple example (where the block of code to run prints the name of the thread) would look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory() {

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            System.out.println("New thread created: " + t); //Your block of code
            return t;
        }
    });

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(150);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        executor.submit(r);
    }

    executor.shutdown();
}
```